# Is practical psychophysics based on science?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

My girlfriend visited a place in Latvia associated with the [Institute of Practical Psychophysics](http://www.uk.metatron-nls.ru/main.php?id=29).

A number of aspects have made me skeptical, including recommendations for products from health food stores and for items not available in the UK.

Their site claims:

> Non-linear analysis systems (NLS) are the most advanced information technologies available in this century and can be considered the most remarkable and advantageous accomplishment of modern natural science. The diagnosis equipment is based on the spectral analysis of the vortex magnetic field of any biological object. It is quite unique and unparalleled in the world today.
>
> The researches of the Institute succeeded in producing this most effective equipment that is capable of tuning to the frequency of the master pulses automatically without human intervention, as well as, detecting and correcting defects and pathologies in organs and body cell on its own. This is achieved through combination of different specifically modulated magnetic oscillations recorded on a matrix. The fundamental concept in the development of this equipment was the hypothesis that the human body has an electromagnetic information framework that is able to respond to external radiation.

Is practical psychophysics a legitimate medicine?

Comment: You asked two very different questions: in the title and at the last sentence of your post. For the second one, you'll need a Latvian lawyer to answer. For the first one, [it's probably based on _economics_](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+economics+a+science&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb)

Comment: @belisarius: unless you, as I did, interpret "legitimate medicine" as "scientific medicine".

Comment: Anyway, my woo-o-meter beeps when I see "vortex magnetic field".

Comment: @mike3 My interpretation has a lot more chances of being answered with a positive :)

Comment: "Spectral analysis of the vortex magnetic field of any biological object" **BWOOT** **BWOOT** **BWOOT** Nonsense technobabble alert!

Comment: @belisarius: I suppose so. But I still think it's woo. :)

Comment: @Shadur But no QCD, Higgs Boson, Dark Matter ... it's utterly incomplete